# Calling deleteRecord() too often or too fast at a time?

Tags: ember-data

I want to delete all records of the model "Article" (around five pieces). I'm doing it like that:

```
CMS.ArticlesController = Em.ArrayController.extend
    deleteAll: ->
        @get("content").forEach (article) ->
            article.deleteRecord()
```

However, while executing, it says after three articles:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'deleteRecord' of undefined
```

It works though when using a little delay:

```
CMS.ArticlesController = Em.ArrayController.extend
    deleteAll: ->
        @get("content").forEach (article) ->
            setTimeout( (->
                article.deleteRecord()
            ), 500)
```

Why is that?

(Im using Ember.js-rc.1 and Ember Data rev 11 together with the `ember-localstorage-adapter` by *@rpflorence*, but I don't think that matter since I didn't call `commit()` yet...)

#### Update 1

Just figured out it also works with `Ember.run.once`...

#### Update 2

I opened a GitHub issue: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/772

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed [on GitHub](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/772), the `forEach()`-loop breaks, because it breaks the index while removing items.

The solution:

"Copy" it in another array using toArray():

```
@get("content").toArray().forEach(article) -> 
    article.deleteRecord()
```

The nicer approach, if there was a function like `forEachInReverse`, is to loop backwards, so even though items are removed, the missing index wouldn't hurt the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I still had issues with the above answer. Instead, I used a reverse for loop:

```
for(var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   items.objectAt(i).destroyRecord(); // or deleteRecord()
}
```

This destroys each item without disrupting the index.